# list the installed python development environment within Anaconda

Tags: python, anaconda

I installed Anaconda pretty long time ago, but I forgot which name I used to setup the python development environment? Are there any commands that can allow me to list all the installed environments? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the docs: https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html

try: `conda info --envs`

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#viewing-a-list-of-your-environments) is specified that you can list installed environments with 2 different commands:

1. `conda info --envs`
2. `conda env list`

Answer (score 1):

The [Conda Cheatsheet](https://conda.io/docs/_downloads/conda-cheatsheet.pdf) will help you here. To simply list all of your installed Conda environments, open a terminal and type:

```
$ conda env list
```

As for `git branch`, the active environment (default on `base`) will be shown with a `*`.